# Tool to automatically insert xml comments in C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm about to take over a C# project whose previous developers generally didn't bother to insert xml comments in front of public declarations.  As a result I get ~1000 warnings when I build (most due to this problem).  This deluge completely buries any useful warning information so I'd like to make it go away; at the same time writing the full complement of missing comments at once is prohibitively time consuming even assuming I could easily figure out all of the methods to do so.

I know I could just disable the warning in visual studio; but I only want to make the noise go away from existing code.  I'd prefer to still be reminded about when I forget to add comments for any new code that I write.  If it exists I'd like to be able to create empty placeholder comments to turn off the warnings on existing methods before I start doing anything else with the code.

Something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="foo"></param>
/// <param name="bar"></param>
/// <param name="baz"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int DoStuff(int foo, double bar, string baz)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) -- I've used it to insert these comment templates.  It even takes a stab at a summary line based on the method name.

Comment: It won't do it for all 1000 warnings though, he will have to go through and manually do it. http://weblogs.asp.net/rweigelt/archive/2005/04/15/400951.aspx

Comment: @Brandon: GhostDoc Pro has a file-at-a-time or type-at-a-time option, which might be faster... (in other words, he'll give in if you pay him XD)

Comment: @Brandon: It won't do all the 1000 or so but it's at least going to get him through the process faster.

Comment: and Alex, oh I agree. I use GhostDoc myself. Didn't mean it as a negative comment towards the answer, just pointing it out in case he expected a solution wide type fix.

Comment: At the point of having to do it all manually one method/property at a time; and not knowing enough about the app to be able to judge if the auto-generated text is valid I'm not sure if I'd actually be getting anything of value.  Completely empty comments don't have any false imprimatur of legitimacy to their content.

Comment: Is there any more modern tool? GhostDoc doesn't support VS 2019

Answer (score 0):

It feels like I am 12 years late however, you can try this [cxCommenter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KhaledMdTuhidulHossain.CXCommenter)

[image]

It can do these functionality now :

1. Add Header summary for C# file.
2. Add Namespace summary.
3. Add Function summary with parameter and return type.
4. Add Property summary.